# Batch file appending text to the end of a .txt file is locking the file

Tags: batch-file, cmd, locking, append, del

We have a process that uses a batch file which, in short, repeatedly gets some plain text data and appends it to the end of a .txt file for later processing. When the data is processed, the .txt is deleted.

This is done in a very simple and basic way by using the ">>" operator to append the data to the .txt file, then a 'DEL' cmd to delete the .txt file.

However, one user is having an issue running this. They are able to append data to the .txt file but are unable to delete it as the file seems to be locked. They get this message when the batch file tries to delete:

"The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process."

The .txt file being created is on a network drive, and no other user is able to delete the file (or change it, etc.) either.

However, if the user with the problem reboots their PC, the file is able to be edited and deleted (which seems to suggest that there is some process on the user's PC that is using the file).

The below batch file is an extremely simplified demo I made which experiences the issue for the user, but not for anyone else. This is not the 'real' process of course, but illustrates the issue without any superfluous code and is totally independent of anything else that the main process is doing.

```
:: we want to repeatedly append text to the end of a txt file
echo test >> test.txt
echo test >> test.txt
echo test >> test.txt

pause

:: but then we cannot delete the file as it appears to be locked
del test.txt

pause
```

The user with the issue has just got a new PC using Windows 10. Everyone else is using Windows 7. Maybe that is the root of the issue, but I don't know why? I understand that command prompt had some changes for Win10, but they sound pretty cosmetic.

Any pointers would be appreciated. I've been scouring the Internet for hours and can't find anything like this issue. Maybe I am doing something so fundamentally wrong that no one would have encountered this?!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: My first suspect would be anti-malware scanners running on the machine. But it's unusual for those to cause a sharing violation, especially in a simple case like this.

Comment: BTW, the console (conhost.exe) was significantly updated in Windows 10, but, AFAIK, nothing significantly changed in the cmd shell. I assume that's what you mean by the changes being cosmetic, i.e. changes to the console UI.

Answer (score 0):

I'm having a similar problem on Windows 7 that produces the same error message but my circumstances are a bit different. In my case, I have a batch file open in an editor, I make changes, and save it. Then I run the batch file and it completes and closes the console window. I make changes and attempt to save the file again and get the same error message. If I wait 30 seconds or so I can then save the batch file again but when I run it again I get the same error.

It doesn't matter how I close the console window. I can let the batch file complete and close the window or terminate the batch file through Task Manager or click the X in the top, right corner of the window and get the same results.

It also doesn't matter what editor I use. I get the same results.

In my case, the file is on a local drive (C:) but that drive does have a drive mapping for the network but no other machines are running.

Do you encounter the same problem if the .txt file is created locally, e.g. C:?

If the Win10 machine is using a drive mapping, do you get the same problem if you use a UNC rather than a drive mapping?

In my case the console window is closed so I know cmd.exe is not holding the file open but I'm wondering if it is something to do with memory management or garbage collection.

Can the user delete the file if they log off and back on rather than rebooting?

There is one other thing that might cause. Windows now has something called "delayed writes". I've run into this problem occasionally in batch files. Try putting a delay in the batch file instead of a pause using something like

```
PING 0.0.0.1 -n 3 -w 1000>NUL 2>&1
```

Just to see if it affects anything.